# React state not updating, using useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state

I have an form data object being stored using `useState`. `shoppinglist` then stores an array of products with certain information. I am able to save an array of data to with no problem.

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    // ...
    shoppinglist: [
      {
        id: '',
        sku: '',
        description: '',
        qty: null,
      },
    ],
  });
```

The problem comes when trying to update a specific value contained in the array of objects. For example, I am trying to update the quantity  for a certain array item, but it keeps erroring.

I am calling `setFormData` and passing in the index of the array item I wish to update using `productIndex`, but I keep getting a `TS` error: `Cannot find name 'shoppinglist'`.

```
setFormData({ ...formData, [shoppinglist[productIndex]]: { qty: qtyValue }});
```

I'm not sure what i'm missing here, but if anyone can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Comment: `formData.shoppinglist[productIndex]`, but there are other issues. You will lose all values besides `qty` inside the updated object. You have to replace the entire object, it won't automatically combine the old with the new

Comment: @BrianThompson `setFormData( ...formData.shoppinglist[productIndex], qty: qtyValue );` returns Cannot find name 'qty'?

Comment: ahhh right, so there isn't away to just update a specific value?

Comment: There's a lot to this. I'm trying to write a complete answer for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's several small issues that all need to be corrected before your update will work.

I will try to step through each one so that it's clear why each part needs corrected. Notice that it's not expected to work fully until the end.

1. You have to reference the whole path to the `shoppinglist` value

`shoppinglist` is not a variable, but a value inside of your state object. You will always need to reference it that way - `formData.shoppinglist`.

2. Update state with same nested structure as original

The update as-is (assuming it would work) would no longer have `shoppinglist` in it. `[shoppinglist[productIndex]]: { qty: qtyValue }` has not been placed inside that object key.

Replace `shoppinglist` first:

```js
setFormData({
  ...formData,
  shoppinglist: [
    ...formData.shoppinglist,
    [formData.shoppinglist[productIndex]]: { qty: qtyValue }
  ]
});
```

3. JavaScript arrays cannot be updated with the syntax you are trying to use

To immutably update a value of an array, you will need to use a method like `map` to create a new array and replace the entry you need to update.

```js
setFormData({
  ...formData,
  shoppinglist: formData.shoppinglist.map((product, i) => {
    if (i == productIndex) {
      return ({ qty: qtyValue });
    }
    return product;
  })
});
```

4. Replace all values for each object/array you are modifying

With the code above, you will update the object, but it will actually lose all of the values except for `qty`. This is because you are defining a completely new object for that index

```js
setFormData({
  ...formData,
  shoppinglist: formData.shoppinglist.map((product, i) => {
    if (i == productIndex) {
      return ({ ...product, qty: qtyValue });
    }
    return product;
  })
});
```

Here we just add `...product` to the new object so that `qty` gets overwritten, but everything else stays the same as before.

5. Use a state updater function for protection against stale closures

You run the risk of using old data when updating state based on old state. The best practice in this situation is to use a function as the argument to `setFormData` that accepts the current state as it's parameter

```js
setFormData((previousState) => ({
  ...previousState,
  shoppinglist: previousState.shoppinglist.map((product, i) => {
    if (i == productIndex) {
      return ({ ...product, qty: qtyValue });
    }
    return product;
  })
}));
```

Notice I just changed the references from `formData` to `previousState`

Comment: That worked! Thank you for writing this, explained it well :) 

I had tried a version using using `prevState` but I missed a few steps.

Comment: Glad it helped. Nested data structures can take a while to get comfortable with. Especially when updates have to be immutable. Something to consider to simplify this and future states you may have - consider using multiple smaller states, such as one specifically for the `shoppinglist` array. This removes one level of nesting and could make life easier

Comment: Thats a good point breaking the form down to use separate states for certain values would work quiet well.